# jqplot external data with async call?

Tags: ajax, json, asynchronous, jqplot, freeze

Is there a way to load external data into jqplot with async call?
I want a live graph that updates every minute, but with async:false the page freezez every time when the data is recieving from server.

Comment: If it's synchronous, it has to freeze while loading.

Comment: well async:true loads in background, but to load external data i have to use async:false and that stops running code until data is loaded

Comment: why? why cant you load external data using an asynchronous request? what library are you using for loading the JSON?

Comment: standart jqplot example here > http://www.jqplot.com/tests/data-renderers.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it was done that way in the example was for simplicity's sake. The following is an async reworking of [this](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/data-renderers.php):

```
var plot2 = null;

function fetchAjaxData(url, success) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(data) {
            success(data);
            console.log('loaded');
        }
    });
}

function createPlot(url) {
    fetchAjaxData(url, function(data) {
        if (plot2 == null) {
            plot2 = $.jqplot('chart2', data, {
                title: "AJAX JSON Data Renderer"
            });
        } else {
            plot2.replot({data: data});
            console.log('replotting');
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var jsonurl = "./jsondata.txt";

    //Regenerate the plot on button click.
    $('#ajax-button').click(function() {
        createPlot(jsonurl);
    });

    //Generate the plot first time through.
    createPlot(jsonurl);
});
```

And with HTML:

```
<div id="chart2" style="height:300px; width:500px;"></div>
<button id="ajax-button">Ajax retrieve</button>
```

So what this does is asynchronously fetch the data and plot it when the Ajax call succeeds. To keep it simple I am just reloading that same text file, though this could easily be adapted to scenarios where you are plotting a live data stream.

Comment: Am I being dense? I can't see why the replot would update the graph with new data?

Comment: After a bit of testing, did you mean plot2.replot({data:data})?

Comment: Following this example I can't figure out where to put the zoom listener, the zoom reset listener, the resize listener and the history checkbox listener. Also, the series with the labels are not correctly positioned.